# Is it the crown that makes the king or, is it his throne?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

This puzzle is quite literal so, rather than keeping it boring I dressed it up a little. The trivia question is in the frame:

```
/*       _\|/_
         (o o)
 +----oOO-{_}-OOo------------------------------------------+
 |In English custom;                                       |
 |Is it the crown that makes the king or, is it his throne?|
 +--------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Clue #1

> The ASCII art is not part of the question.

Clue #2

> As stated in the introduction the question is literal.

Clue #3

> Since this is Puzzling.SE, it is possible that the question contains misdirection.

Clue #4

> Some (I will not say how many) of the existing answers may be getting onto the right trail.

Clue #5

> Makes is an interesting word: cause (something) to exist or come about; bring about. But, don't be misled even though it is literal - we are talking about the king in the context of the question, not where he came from.

Comment: Hey there, Kilroy.

Comment: you wern't kidding when you said you'd dress it up but who's the mystery man in the back?

Comment: @L_Church [Kilroy was here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilroy_was_here) as alluded to by Ian.

Comment: Voting to reopen as the OP has added 4 hints and an edit that help make the puzzle better specified.

Comment: Voting to reopen as the solution seems very obvious and the question is well readable now

Comment: Voting to reopen, less broad now.

Comment: The comma seems misplaced to me, is that intentional?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle; it is simply a trivia question (based on the answer provided [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6349/4421)).

Comment: @MickO'Hea It is a bit like an Oxford comma.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that we are literally talking about how to "Make" a king. Therefore,

> you give birth to it.
>  A major step in the birthing of a king (or anyone else), is the **CROWNING**, as many kings are born into their position.

Comment: This is my favorite answer.

Answer (score 3):

> The Crown, I'm thinking that this refers to the game of Chequers and the act of crowning makes a king.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Why do you believe that that's what the puzzle is referring to?

Comment: Only thing I could think of and also the way the question was framed.

Comment: A fine answer but, unfortunately not literal enough. Those are metaphorical kings.

Answer (score 1):

So the question is literal, right? Perhaps the answer is simply:

> No!

Because.

> Kings aren't "made" by their throne or their crown, but rather in the same way every other person is "made".

Comment: @noedne Thanks for editing the spoilers in. My phone just doesn't seem to like making them work.

Comment: Oh my goodness! A valiant attempt, I certainly did not foresee that one. Now, how the heck can I possible clarify the question better..

Answer (score 0):

Going by the fundamental rule,

> It is the base that determines, what you are / who you are - and hence it is the throne!. By the way, crowns can be mocked up whereas it is not an easy case with throne/s. Also, after climbing a throne, one usually gets declared as a king, but not necessarily be crowned.

Comment: The point that this answer makes is getting closer.

Answer (score 0):

> It's the crown because the only way we can see that the little character is indeed the king is that he is wearing a crown.

Comment: A fine answer, however, the question is literal. Note also the trivia tag.

Answer (score 0):

> It is the crown (verb) that makes the king.
>   [**crown**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/crown?s=t): to invest with a regal crown, or with regal dignity and power (in other words, to make someone king or monarch).
>   There is no verb 'to throne'

Comment: It is true that the definition of the verb `crown` states that (the part in brackets is a source of much confusion).

Answer (score 0):

If we happen to be talking about:

> chess

then I'd say:

> The **throne**, as a piece's type is determined by the square it is placed on to start.  It is the QUEEN that traditionally represented by a crown.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, attempt 2:

> The crown as in English the crown often refers to the reigning monarchs themselves. Here the crown is referring to the king's parents (who would have been king and or queen at the time and refered to as "the crown")

Answer (score 0):

2nd attempt

If we take it as litteral as possible I would then say

> none of the two

because

> in the case of the english monarchy, you become king immediatly after the previous king dies, before you get the crown or the throne

a famous exemple is

> Edward I of England who became king during the 9th crusade while he was away

Comment: A truely valiant attempt. Only missing the actual answer.